# Did entityframework support json query?

Tags: json, entity-framework

Json query was supported in SQL Server 2016,

So I save my data as json in it.

But how can i using json query in my code

Entity Model:

```
public class MyModel
{
   public string JsonData { get; set; }
}

public class MyEntity : DbContext
{
   public MyEntity() : base("name=MyDB")
   {
   }

   public DbSet<MyModel> MyModels { get; set; }
}
```

How to use it to query json maybe like:

```
using(var db = new MyEntity())
{
   var result = db.MyModels.Where(r => r.JsonData["Person"]["Name"] == "Sam");
}
```